# How can we match extension less files using wildcard expression?

Tags: shell, wildcard

I have   files with extension and without extensions in my web directory

```
foo
bar
me.php
```

How can I match those files that have no extensions at the end,using wildcard expression?

I have tried many methods but all failed

1)

```
*.*
```

it returns all files with or without extension

2)

```
*[a-z]*
```

returned none

then I tried to negate the dot so that it can return files without extensions only

```
*[a-z][!.]*
```

it also did not work.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by match? How should it be matched? Because using `ls *.*` only return for me `me.php`, nothing else

Comment: How can it return extension less files only?("foo" "bar" not "me.php")

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to activate the `extglob` function in the shell.

You can do this by:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

This will give you more powerful matching patterns.

Then you can get what you want by:

```
ls !(*.*)
```

and turn it off afterwards using

```
shopt -u extglob
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than `extglob`, you can also use this `find` command to list all files in current directory without any extension:

```
find . -regex '\./[^.]*$' -maxdepth 1 -type f
```